# Uploading a sketch causing an error message in Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

avrdude:

> no programmer has been specified on the command line or the config
>   file
>            Specify a programmer using the -c option and try again

Answer (score 1):

On the "Tools" menu choose "Programmer:" and specify AVRISP mkII; be sure that you've also chosen the appropriate "Board:" entry for the Uno.
[image]

Comment: yeah i  know all that but it keeps showing me the same error!!!

Comment: Describe your environment:  Windows? Unix, which one? Which version of the Arduino IDE?  Or, are you using Eclipse or another IDE?  Perhaps you need to re-install?  Has it ever worked?  Does, "Get Board Info" work?

Comment: Oh, are you trying to use the command line tool (avrdude?)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it. I just reinstalled the drivers.